# FATAL: No bootable medium found! GUI

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, lubuntu

I want to change the GUI in my virtual machine. I have Lubuntu distribution but I want to work with gnome so I installed gnome and then when I rebooted the machine and "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted" messag sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop

e appears and I don't know how to do to get gnome environment.

Command
`sudo apt update` and
`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: You'll need to provide specific commands and details as to what you did.  What system did you start with (legacy Lubuntu with LXDE or modern Lubuntu with LXQt, release details are needed). What command did you install GNOME with?  `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` would not impact the booting of the system, so what exactly did you do?

Comment: Still, it does not make sense: Lubuntu and Ubuntu differ only in their respective DE. Install Ubuntu and get gnome - for whatever reasons you chose that Gnome DE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your Virtual machine, you have installed linux from live-cd. Just see boot settings in your VM app, select drive from which will be loaded your system.
Maybe it helps you.

Comment: She started that VM installed Lubuntu and then decided to install Gnome (for whatever reasons ;-) So the VM works -that has nothing to do with the boot settings.